# Convert datetime from Excel to R

Tags: r, excel, datetime

I read an excel file with `library(readxl)`

In excel I have format: `9/14/2017  7:58:58 AM` in R it ends up `42992.332615740743`. How can I bring back to human readable format in R?

Do I need supply `origin` for `as.POSIXct`? What is the `origin`?

Comment: @TeeKea it is excel file, which I read with `library(readxl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to read the datetime column as `"date"` in order to be able to convert it. For example, if you have the following excel file:

```
ID    Name     Date
1     aaa      9/14/2017  7:58:58 AM
2     bbb      2/23/2017  5:22:01 PM
3     bbb      7/10/2017  10:37:19 PM
```

You would need to read it as followS:

```
excel_data <- read_excel("test.xls", col_types = c("numeric", "text", "date"))
```

If you have a long list of columns, you can just specify the `col_types` as `guess`, like this:

```
excel_data <- read_excel("test.xls", col_types = "guess")
```

---

Now, to convert into to a readable datetime in R, you would need to use `as.POSIXct` with the `origin` value as `1899-12-30`, as follows:

```
excel_data$Date <- as.POSIXct(excel_data$Date,
                              origin="1899-12-30",
                              tz="GMT")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It gave me error `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`.

Comment: Weird. Just worked fine for me. How do you read the data? Like this: `excel_data <- read_excel("test.xls", col_types = "date")`

Comment: I read it as `excel_data <- read_excel("test.xls", col_types = "text")`, Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: I see. That is the problem. I just got the same error as yours when I read the the datetime column as `text`. Read it like this `excel_data <- read_excel("test.xls", col_types = c("date", "numeric", "text"))`, where `date` is for a datetime column, `numeric` for a numeric column, and `text` for a text column.

Comment: Thank you! I might try it. There are tones of columns, and I don't want to specify each type manually. I will rather convert it to csv first.

Comment: Can you try `excel_data <- read_excel("test.xls", col_types = "guess")` ? It will solve your problem with having a lot of columns.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function `convert_date` in package [`datetimeutils`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=datetimeutils) (which I maintain).

```
library("datetimeutils")
convert_date(42992.332615740743, type = "Excel", fraction = TRUE)
## [1] "2017-09-14 07:58:58 CEST"
```

Since Excel does not keep track of the timezone, `R` will use the system's timezone, unless you specify a different one.

```
convert_date(42992.332615740743, type = "Excel", fraction = TRUE, tz = "UTC")
## [1] "2017-09-14 07:58:58 UTC"
```

Comment: I tried to use this library however I get an error that there is no such package.  It turns out that it needs to be installed, and RStudio takes a bit of time to catch on (at least on my computer)

Comment: @SwiftArrow: you can install any R package on CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/index.html) by simply saying `install.packages("<pkg.name>"`. This has nothing to do with RStudio. So here, simply say `install.packages("datetimeutils")`.